# Juice accordion not collapsing

Tags: asp.net, juice-ui

This is my first attempt to implement this on my page.I have gone through several samples including the the default sample given [here][1]

[1]: http://juiceui.com/controls/accordion. I implemented exactly base on the sample provide on that link. But still my page is not collapsing.Did any one know what am doing wrong.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<juice:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" Collapsible="false" AutoHeight="True">
    <juice:AccordionPanel ID="AccordionPanel1" Title="System Setup" runat="server">
        <PanelContent>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Pharmacy/SetUp/Newtreatment.aspx">New Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="Pharmacy/SetUp/Newdrug.aspx">New Drug</a></li>
                <li><a href="Pharmacy/SetUp/drugcost.aspx">Drug Cost</a></li>
            </ul>
        </PanelContent>
    </juice:AccordionPanel>
    <juice:AccordionPanel ID="AccordionPanel2" Title="Treatment" runat="server">
        <PanelContent>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Treatment/newprescription.aspx">Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="Treatment/Requestlab.aspx">Lab Request</a></li>
            </ul>
        </PanelContent>
    </juice:AccordionPanel>
    <juice:AccordionPanel ID="AccordionPanel3" Title="Laboratory" runat="server">
        <PanelContent>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="LabManagement/Adminitration/newtest.aspx">New Lab Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="LabManagement/Adminitration/TestExamination.aspx">Examination</a></li>
            </ul>
        </PanelContent>
    </juice:AccordionPanel>
    <juice:AccordionPanel ID="AccordionPanel4" runat="server" Title="Payment Department">
        <PanelContent>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="PaymentDepartment/payment.aspx">Bills</a></li>
            </ul>
        </PanelContent>
    </juice:AccordionPanel>
    <juice:AccordionPanel ID="AccordionPanel5" runat="server" Title="Reports">
        <PanelContent>
            <ul>
                <li>Medical Certificate</li>
                <li>Death Certifificate</li>
            </ul>
        </PanelContent>
    </juice:AccordionPanel>
</juice:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally got the solution provided by another person on stackoverflow:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
  <Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"/>
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"/>
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Now i wnat to control the width.It occupied the whole page